# WSPBuilder for vs 2012

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, wspbuilder

I am new to SharePoint 2013. I am using trial version vs 2012. I want to use the WSPBuilder to develop the web parts. I have install the WSPBuilder and it is not showing in vs 2012.

I have used the below link but not solved the issue.

http://gblsharepoint.blogspot.in/2013/01/using-wspbuilder-with-visual-studio-2012.htm

I have done the copy and past the "Microsoft Visual Studio" and "Microsoft Visual Studio Macros" hot applications and given the version as "11.0". It is working.

Can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

WSP builder is used only for 2007 development. Use CKS dev instead. This is valable for both 2010 and 2012 VS

You can find it [here](http://sharepoint-community.net/forum/topics/cks-dev-for-visual-studio-2012-is-now-available?xg_source=activity).

Hope it helps,

Andrew